# Finding an integer in a non sorted array using recursion and dividing

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, divide

I need a little help with finding an integer in an array. The array must be non sorted, and the algorithm must be done recursively. My peers and I have came up with the solution to cut the array in half, check if the middle number is the value we are looking for, if not, it cuts itself in half and keeps repeating itself, until it moves on to other parts of the array and eventually stops. So far, I have been experimenting with my code, here it is. I would like to know where this is going wrong, and how can I improve it or make it fully work? Thank you

```
import java.util.*;
public class BinarySearch {
public static int search(int[] a, int low, int high, int value, int count)
{
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if(a[mid] == value)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    if(a[mid] < value)
    {
        count = a[mid];
        if(a[count] != value)
        {
            count--;
            return search(a, mid + 1, high, value, count);

        }


    }
    else
    {
        count = a[mid];
        if(a[count] != value){
        count++;
        return search(a, low, mid - 1, value, count);
        }
    }

return low;



}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
BinarySearch BS = new BinarySearch();
int[] a = {5, 7, 1, 2, 4, 12, 9, 8, 89};
int value = 9;
int result = BS.search(a, 0, 0, value, 0);
if(result == -1)
{
    System.out.print("the Value is not in the array!" );
}
else
{
    System.out.print("the Value is in the array!" );

}
}
}
```

Comment: It's not binary search. Binary search requires a sorted array.

Comment: Binary search is for a sorted structure. If the array is not sorted then you can't assume anything about either half of the array. You need to search in both.

Comment: _"I would like to know where this is going wrong"_ Have you tried to use the debugger ? Or simply with a pen and paper, following the execution of your algorithm with the small input you have ?

Comment: Don't complicate the problem by using a binary approach.  you can still use recursion with a linear approach: For example, is the first element in the array the target?  If not, call recursion which excludes that element.  Each recursive call reduces the size of the array by 1, until the element is found, or the array is empty.

Comment: I have tried using a pen and paper, I know that binary search requires a sorted array. What I need to do is basically break the array into 2 parts, get the first part of it, find the middle of it, if its not the value i am looking for, it chooses one part of the half i broke up, and finds the middle of that, and so one, until it finds the value i asked. But i cant seem to figure out how to have it to keep changing the parts it goes to and where do all the numbers end up in the end. Should I be removing variables as I go?

Comment: Since the array is not sorted you basically just need to search one by one. Binary search requires a sorted array.